# Run maven project that has profile with junit runner

Tags: java, maven, selenium, junit

My pom.xml has `<systemPropertyVariables>` and `<profiles>`. Right now if I want to run it as a maven build i am using `-DXXX` for system property variables and `-PXXX` for profiles in the goal.
Now I would like to run this as JUnit test in eclipse. I found that system property variables  can be given in VMArguments. 
Now the problem is how to access this profile. Here is how my profile looks like

```
<profile>
    <id>devqa</id>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/devqa</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</profile>
```

I have a file in the resource location and im accessing it in my test

```
File testfile = new File(this.getClass().getResource("/config.properties").toURI());
```

I tried to give this in Active Maven Profiles but it didn't work. How to make this work

Comment: I have to admin I don't understand your question. Cause you wrote you have done `mvn -Pdevqa` ? And what is exactly the problem here? Can elaborate more in detail what you like to achieve?

Comment: I am able to run project as mvn project. I would like to run it as Junit test now.

Comment: Are you looking for `mvn test`?

Comment: This is the setup I have for running as a maven build
-f pom.xml test -DbrowserName=chrome -DexecPlatform=native -Pdevqa
This works perfectly fine.
Now the problem is I have a runner file 
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
   
  )
public class WorkbenchSmoke {
 
}
I would like to run the project with this runner as Junit from eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Add the resource path `src/main/resources/devqa` to junit run configuration class path using add projects widget. It may work.

Comment: Tried but no luck